# SQL / Access Query - How do I append two records for every one master record? Time Cards

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a list of records in TBL_WheelHours with the following Schema:

```
**GUID - Operator 1 - Operator 2 - Data1 - Data2 - Data3 - Data4 Etc.**
```

I have a set of queries that append all new entries from this table to another table called TBL_CostLog.

What I want to do is create two entries in the cost log that looks as such:

```
**TableID - GUID - Operator 1 - Data1 etc.**

**TableID - GUID - Operator 2 - Data1 etc.**
```

And then I want to be able to run an update query using Tbl Wheel hours as the master, so if that any information in that table changed it propagates to the cost log.

I have many other tables and queries doing this exact same thing and its working beautifully.  The difference here though is that there are two operators on this machine, and only 1 record with both names on it.

Any advice or direction I should pursue to do this?

EDIT:

Here is what I have for the other tables where this is not an issue:

**APPEND QUERY**

```
INSERT INTO TBL_TimeLog ( Customer, RefNumber, StartTime, StopTime, Multiplier, FromTable, WorkType, [TableID], ProductID, QtySprayed, CoatDesc, Operator_1, Operator_2 )

SELECT TBL_BlastHours.Customer, TBL_BlastHours.[WO #], TBL_BlastHours.[Start Time], TBL_BlastHours.[Stop Time], "1" AS Expr1, "Blast" AS Expr2, "Blast" AS Expr3, TBL_BlastHours.IDLoc, "NA" AS Expr4, 0 AS Expr5, TBL_BlastHours.Booth, TBL_BlastHours.Blaster, "NA" AS Expr6

FROM TBL_BlastHours 

LEFT JOIN TBL_TimeLog ON TBL_BlastHours.IDLoc = TBL_TimeLog.TableID

WHERE (((TBL_TimeLog.TableID) Is Null));
```

**UPDATE QUERY**

```
UPDATE TBL_BlastHours 

INNER JOIN TBL_TimeLog 
ON TBL_BlastHours.IDLoc = TBL_TimeLog.TableID 
SET TBL_TimeLog.Customer = [TBL_BlastHours].[Customer], TBL_TimeLog.RefNumber = [TBL_BlastHours].[WO #], TBL_TimeLog.StartTime = [TBL_BlastHours].[Start Time], TBL_TimeLog.StopTime = [TBL_BlastHours].[Stop Time], TBL_TimeLog.CoatDesc = [TBL_BlastHours].[Booth], TBL_TimeLog.Operator_1 = [TBL_BlastHours].[Blaster], TBL_TimeLog.Operator_2 = "NA"

WHERE (((TBL_TimeLog.FromTable)="Blast"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select guid, operator1, data1
from tbl_wheelhours
union all
select guid, operator2, data1
from tbl_wheelhours;
```

From your description, you may also need a trigger.  However, you say have similar code working for a single record, so `union all` might be the missing piece.

Comment: So this creates what I am looking for, but how can I then append these records to a seperate table?  Also, how would I create an update query when the GUID is the same for 2 records on that table?

Comment: You would but an `insert` before them.  As for the `GUID` being the same, that appears to be what your question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the results I want.  I added a column called OperatorKey and OperatorFlag

Append new entries as I had been doing, with all new entries having "1" in the operator flag.  I then append a second set of entries with the second operator for all entries that have "1" with the operator flag.

I then run an update query that changes all operator flags to "0".

I create a unique Operator Key for each entry, and then I can run two update queries with the operator key and the GUID key and update the entries from the master list.

Seems to be working great for now.